# On Windows, when will a 'socket()' call return WSAEPROTONOSUPPORT?

Tags: sockets, winapi, networking, winsock2

Suppose our client application does as below:

```
WSADATA wsa_data;
int     ret;
SOCKET  sock;
ret = WSAStartup (MAKEWORD (2, 2), &wsa_data);
if (ret ==0) {
  sock = socket (AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPROTO_UDP);
}
```

When will it happen that `sock == INVALID_SOCKET` and `WSAGetLastError()` would return `WSAEPROTONOSUPPORT`?

Microsoft's documentation for the `socket()` function says it can return `WSAEAFNOSUPPORT` when:

> Protocol not supported i.e UDP/TCP .
> The requested protocol has not been configured into the system, or no implementation for it exists.

I have seen that this error mainly comes if I am explicitly passing a protocol.

Is there a possibility that the protocol is not supported by the OS itself (ie, it is not configured in the system itself) and this error can come during a `socket()` call?

If yes, why? Under what circumstances? And how can it be remedied?

Comment: `WSAEPROTONOSUPPORT` indicates that the specified protocol is not supported by the protocol family,

Comment: yes, So is it possible that the Protocol family is itself not supported by OS?If yes, why? Under what circumstances? And how can it be remedied?

Comment: In what environment do you get such an error, could you explain your test environment? or provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)